# Issues with divs

Tags: html, css

Im have about 20 of these setups below.
Each one contains an image and 2 links
I need each div with a link in it to stack and stay like that and those links stack under the grow div with an image in it.

Each one of these setups needs to sit next to each other. So all the mainwraps will be next to each other like they are floated left type of thing.

How can i have it so that it works how i need it to?

If i set mainwrap to `width:100%` the individualwraps sit how i need them but then the mainwrap takes up `100%` and i cant sit another mainwrap next to it so on and so forth.

I hope this makes sense as im half asleep

**HTML:**

```
<div class="mainwrap">
<div class=" grow">image</div>

<div class="individualwrap">link</div>
<div class="individualwrap">link</div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.grow {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 177px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Ive made an image to show my idea

[www.techagesite.com/idea.png http://www.techagesite.com/idea.png](http://www.techagesite.com/idea.png)

Comment: What kind of browser support do you need?

Comment: ok but if you have tried it, show us how it works not only how you want it

Comment: Never heard of css columns so how am i meant to search for them. in all my div searching over the past 2mths ive never landed on a page for css columns. If i could do a search and end up on a page with the answer then i wouldnt be here.

Comment: @Techagesite Im confused of what exactly you want, something like this? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S7GDj/)

Comment: @ruddy yeah mate like that. I have it working now tho cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have floated the `mainwrap` elements that you can have a box display. I also have aligned the div with the links in the center. The result can be found in this fiddle. (for image, i took an example, which displays it better then only a text).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PJd65/) example.

```
.mainwrap {
    float: left;
}
.grow{
    margin:0 4px;
    height: 177px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.individualwrap {
    text-align: center;
}
```

If you want that the `.individualwrap` behaves as buttons, then style it as buttons. There are enough examples on the internet which you can use, like [this one](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ButtonMaker/).